# AngularJS ui-select, accessing model data from the on-select method is always one value behind

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Can someone please explain why the following happens?

I use ui-select and have the following html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><p>{{cinema.name}}</p></div>

<div class="col-sm-8">
    <ui-select ng-model="program[cinema.id]" multiple theme="bootstrap" on-select="onSelect(program[cinema.id], cinema.id)" ng-disabled="disabled">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select...">{{$item.name}} - {{$item.code}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="film in filmList | filter: { name: $select.search }">
            {{film.name}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div><!-- /col-sm-8 -->
```

The question is regarding the "on-select" directive.

In my controller I declare the "program" object which will hold the model data.

```
$scope.program = {};
```

When the "onSelect" method is called, I send it the model directly from the "ui-select" directive and the "cinemaId".

If I console log the model which I have just sent from the on-select, It will always show one value short.

If I use the cinemaId, access the "program" model from the $scope inside a verbose timeout, I get the model updated with all the values.

```
$scope.onSelect = function (theModel, cinemaId) {
       console.log(theModel) // this will show the values inside the model, ALWAYS one value behind.

        $timeout(function(){
            console.log($scope.program[cinemaId]);
            // if I do this and I access the model bound to the select from the scope, I get the model with the values updated.
        });
    }
```

Any ideas why?